# Use a formatted field to make mathematic operations

Tags: java

I'm building an app to calculate the time between two times
I added two  formatted fields to get the startime and stop time.

What Can I do to use the formatted fields to calculate the time within two hours? I tried to parse string to float but it does not work

```
float Start, End ,result = 0;
    //Parse the string to a float
    Start = Float.parseFloat(Start_Input.getText());
    End = Float.parseFloat(Stop_Input.getText());
    result = End-Start;
    OutPut_Area.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Comment: You can calculate the difference between two points in time using the `java.time` API

Comment: You can use Duration.between() or Period.between() base on your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use float to accept time? I think use long to accept time is more reasonable when the time is timestamp.

If you use float to accept time, you should use this to calculate:

```
BigDecimal.subtract(new BigDecimal(float doubleValue)).doubleValue()
```

Instead of:

```
-
```